# select on change angular implementation?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel, subject, subject-observer

angularjs has a built in directive called `onchanges` which would listen to changes in a select or whatever and allow you to execute a function upon a change.

How I wish this was so in angular. Currently I am better understanding ngmodel and seeing how I might be able to use a subject to acheive the following.

I have a select of cities:

```
<div id="venueFilterParams" ngModelGroup="venueFilterParams">
          <!-- need to add default values from url-->
          <select [ngModel]="citySelect"
                  name="citySelect"
                  id="citySelect"
                  class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let city of cities" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option> <!--come back and wire up-->
          </select>
```

and a select of neighborhoods:

```
 <select [ngModel]="neighborhoodSelected"
                  name="neighborhood"
                  id="neighborhood"
                  class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let neighborhood of neighborhoodlist" value="{{neighborhood}}">{{neighborhood}}</option>
          </select>
```

If the user selects a city other than the one passed in the URL leading to this page, (which will be default selected I have yet to build that yet)

I need my app to reach out to my database and repopulate the neighborhood select options with the neighboorhoods for that city.

All of that I can do fine, what I am trying to figure out is code which will listen to the city select and run a function which does the above.

Now `[ngModel] = citySelect;` will not on its own update, I have to wait for a submit click to capture the value but what about [(ngModel)] = citySelect and listening to the citySelect variable in a subject?

I'm going to keep working on this but your suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Look into reactive forms, they give you an RxJS stream of all events either for a specific component or the whole form.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe is there a way of doing this without the reactive form? if not I'll get on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has similar directives called (change) or (ngModelChange).

You need two-way data binding if you want to set initial value for the city based on url. For two-way data binding, (ngModelChange) is a way to go.

Therefore, in your city select:

```
<select [ngModel]="citySelect"
    (ngModelChange)="onCityChange($event)"
    name="citySelect"
    id="citySelect"
    class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="{{city}}">{{city}}
  </option> <!--come back and wire up-->
</select>
```

Then, define onCityChange in your component:

```
public onCityChange(chosenCity) {
  console.log(chosenCity);
  // populate neighborhoodlist based on chosenCity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular (v2+) you can bind directly to the javascript DOM events. For a select the event `change` fires whenever the value changes. Therefore you can set up and respond to the event like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="citySelect" (change)="onCityChange()">
```

```js
private onCityChange(): void {
    /* Your custom code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModelChange`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="citySelect" (ngModelChange)="myCitySpecificFunction()">
```

In your component:

```
private myCitySpecificFunction(): void {
    console.log('City updated to ' + this.citySelect);
}
```

Note that `ngModelChange` must be listed *after* `ngModel` on the html element or it won't register.

Comment: (badass name) I thought ngModelChange was for angularjs and no longer used in angular 4?At least thats what I thought I read

Comment: I use it in Angular 2. ☺